# How to style table as flex-wrap but without flexbox

Tags: html, css

My structure of HTML and CSS looks like:

```css
.item {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.item > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="item"><div>0</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>2</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>3</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>4</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>5</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>6</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>7</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>8</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>9</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>10</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to apply to table `flex-wrap: wrap` but I can't use flexbox or grid cuz I am working on email template where 'modern styling methods' are not supported, so I need to use table. So I need to use `flex-wrap` on this table but without using flexbox. I need this to prevent some responsiveness.

Current support of `flex-wrap` in email : [doc](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-wrap/)

Comment: Do you know the size of the table in advance?

Comment: I don't get it, What's going on?

Comment: If you know the size of the table aka table rows you can avoid wrapping and just set the fix size of rows.

Comment: I think table should the entire width of the screen

Answer (score 1):

```css
table{
 display:block}
table td{
display:inline-block;}
.item {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.item > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="item"><div>0</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>2</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>3</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>4</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>5</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>6</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>7</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>8</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>9</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>10</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! One more question, How i can stretch this divs to full width?