# How to position this element in specific way

Tags: html, css

Good Morning!

I have uncomplicated HTML and CSS structure, it looks like this:

```css
.item{
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: table;
}
.item > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>0</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>2</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>3</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>4</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>5</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>6</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>7</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>8</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>9</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>10</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div><div style="text-align: left; font-size: 12.5px;">Zdecydowanie nie polece</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 80%;"><div><div></div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div><div style="text-align: right; font-size: 12.5px;">Zdecydowanie polece</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, on mobile I would like to change a little bit position of this elements. But media query isn't problem. I would like to have something like that:

[image]

The problem is, I can't use any flexbox or grid style methods because I am making template for email purpose. So do you know how we can style this structure to structure from IMG?

Have a nice day!

Comment: If you are doing this for an email client, I don't even think you can use `position: relative;`.

Comment: Emails aren't. ;)

Comment: If you go back to the solution you already got here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69192203/1427878, with the TD elements displayed as `inline-block`, you can probably do it by applying relative positioning and/or margins to every second element - either via `:nth-child(even)`, or if that does not work in mail clients either, by applying inline styles directly.

Comment: I would suggest using any visual editor to create this email.

Comment: Maybe you can wait for the best answer, I would like to learn this too. But in the past, the way I did it with having the same look & feel across all the various email client as my top priority was to slice image (with the white background) in photoshop and put them in table cells created in Outlook. The cells were all given 0 spacing so it looks like a compact image. This allowed me to set links to each section. However, the white background part will have the hover as well.

Comment: You've got your answer on this https://jsfiddle.net/a36m1oce/2/ by another user on the second question you posted, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using tables with the colspan propperty on td, but you'd have to change the markup so that odd and even numbers are in sepparate rows.
Every element would have colspan="2" except the first and the last ones in the second row, which would be empty and have a clospan="1".

Answer (score 0):

```
tbody{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    table tr td .item{
        background: #fb5f66;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="item">0</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">2</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">4</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">6</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">8</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">10</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="item">1</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">3</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">5</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">7</div></td>
            <td><div class="item">9</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).