# How to center div in table

Tags: html, css

I have structure like this:

```css
  .item{
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
  }
  .item > div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile{
  display: none;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop{
      display: none;
  }
  .mobile{
      display: table;
  }
  .mobile tr{
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
  }
  }
```

```html
<table class='desktop' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>0</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%; "><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%; "><div class="item"><div>2</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%; "><div class="item"><div>3</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%; "><div class="item"><div>4</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%; "><div class="item"><div>5</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>6</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>7</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>8</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>9</div></div></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;"><div class="item"><div>10</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='mobile' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td><div class="item"><div>0</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>2</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>4</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>6</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>8</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>10</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>3</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>5</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>7</div></div></td>
        <td><div class="item"><div>9</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/h8a163wj/8/

So on desktop everything is good, as i want.
Now on mobile I would like to center everything to have desired effect
Something like that: [image]

The last thing what i need to do is to center the second div of mobile structure. I write some style but i don't why they aren't working

Comment: You could use transform on even tr's td https://jsfiddle.net/a36m1oce/

Comment: You asked about this already three hours ago. [How to position this element in specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69204425/how-to-position-this-element-in-specific-way)

Comment: stop repeating the same quesiont again and again. Make *one* clear question with all you requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try with `transform`.

```
  .mobile tr:nth-child(even) td {
    transform: translatex(50%)
  }
```

Demo

```css
.item {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.item>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: table;
  }
  .mobile tr {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .mobile tr:nth-child(even) td {
    transform: translatex(50%)
  }
}
```

```html
<table class='desktop' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='mobile' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or `position:relative` <del>if it's about email ([it can be inline-style](https://jsfiddle.net/a36m1oce/1/))</del>

```css
.item {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.item>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: table;
  }
  .mobile tr {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .mobile tr:nth-child(even) td {
    position: relative;
    left: 8%
  }
}
```

```html
<table class='desktop' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='mobile' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`colspan` could help too to avoid `transform` or `position`

```css
.item {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.item>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: table;
  }
  .mobile tr {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

}
```

```html
<table class='desktop' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; ">
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><body class='god'>
<table class='mobile' style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>8</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>10</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="item">
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, but I can't use ntchild cuz I am working on email template, so i need to do inline style

Comment: And i checked - Emails don't support transform

Comment: then, use position:  `.mobile tr:nth-child(even) td {
     position:relative;
     left:8%
   }`

Comment: Email don't support position... Do we live in 1950?xD

Comment: okay, then you will need to use colspan to offset your tds

Comment: Could we give some exmaple?

Comment: added one snippet in the answer or this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a36m1oce/2/ @ProteinDev

Comment: Looks like you already had your answer a few hours ago